# mongoose aggregate keeps node server blocked

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, nonblocking

I have couple hundred thousand documents in my collection, each with a `timestamp` field.

I want to count number of records with respect to each day for the last month.

I'm running a mongoose aggregate command to do that which is unfortunately taking long time than what I was expecting.

Following is the aggregate function:

```
function dailyStats()
{
    var lastMonth = new Date();
    lastMonth.setMonth(lastMonth.getMonth() - 1);

    MyModel.aggregate(
        {
            $match: {timestamp: {$gte: lastMonth}}
        },
        {
            $group: {
                // Data count grouped by date
                _id: {$dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$timestamp"}},
                count: {$sum: 1}
            }
        },
        {$sort: {"_id": 1}},
        function (err, docs)
        {
            console.log(docs);
        });
}
```

Now, whole point of callbacks is non-blocking code. However, when this function is executed, it takes around 20-25 seconds. For this whole time, my node application doesn't respond to other APIs!

First I thought that my CPU gets so busy that its not responding to anything else. So I had a small node app run along with it, which works fine!
So I don't understand why this application does not respond to other requests till mongodb driver returns with the result.